# Our minds are extremely potent devices

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Our **minds are** extremely potent **devices**.

This is a sentence of a novel. But is  **mind** not a single entity? How can we use minds and devices here, which are showing plural form.
Suggestions please. Thank you.

Comment: A mind is a single entity, but a group of people will have several minds, which are quite potent devices.

Comment: Check a few dictionaries online and confirm whether the word in concern can be used as plural? Also, look at the examples they give. This is a permanent solution! Take this word itself. [*minds* is possible](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mind_1?q=mind).

Comment: My mind, your mind, our minds, their minds.... Unless, of course, you're talking about bees or the Borg :)

Comment: @PerryW, even the borg hive mind is still composed of a collective of minds.

Comment: :) That was what I was getting at @Omnidisciplinarianist - if a collective or hive mind can be thought of as both single entity and group then 'My minds' could be a correct usage. We're probably going wildly off-topic now :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Seema, we have numerous definitions of mind. In this particular case, the word is referring to that portion of a person which gives rise to our consciousness and rational capability. Each person has their own.

By using the phrase *our minds* we are speaking of the collection of minds individually, instead of as a single group. As noted by CopperKettle, Maulik and Perry, that collective may be referred to as a single entity (for example: *The mind of this council has decided...*), but it is still composed of many individual sub-entities, each which can be distinctly called a mind.

If you're trying to speak of a groups of minds functioning as a single conceptual entity, likely toward a common purpose, the example could be rewritten as thus:

> Our mind is an extremely potent device.

Finally, let's put that example of the singular into a context where it could be considered natural speech:

> Individually we may not be able to do much, but ***our mind is an extremely potent device***, capable of wonders we'd have no hope of accomplishing alone.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a standard person has 1 mind.

If your subject is multiple people (*our* is a first-person *plural* pronoun), then each person will have their 1 mind, and there will be multiple minds.

It's possible to mean *mind* in the sense you are thinking - that an entire group has 1 mind:

> Our mind is an extremely potent device

Whoever is *our* here, we are saying above that all of them are functioning together under a single mind.

But the original sentence is saying that each person's mind is a potent device individually.